# How could a country broadcast digital data through tap water (instead of radio waves)?

Tags: chemistry

**Background:** I'm toying with the idea of an alternate Earth that never developed wireless technologies. Radio transmitters, Wi-Fi, etc... were never invented, meaning that light-speed communication is practically nonexistent. One nation progressed into the modern world with an extreme grasp on chemistry, synthesizing artifical hydrocarbons and hyper-efficient batteries. Without understanding of the electromagnetic spectrum, however, they have no means of instant digital communication.

**Question:** In a city with no need for underground power lines, the only utility that reaches homes is the tap water line. What are some viable ways that chemists can encode data into tap water itself, replicating widespread communication like radio or television without the need for wireless signals?

*Note:* I'm looking for answers that fit a "chemistry" theme, because my world is divided up into factions who have monopolies on different areas of science. One faction *does* know how to utilize the electromagnetic spectrum, and another *does* know how to encode data into DNA strands. This nation has exclusively chemistry going for it, and nothing else in particular.

Comment: Do you mean by using the water as an electrical conductor or a more mechanical means?

Comment: Handwavium, just like the batteries, nutrition, powerful neutralzers and artificial hydrocarbons.

Comment: @Samuel I'm looking for kind of a *theme* that links all the technology of this country together. If every development is based on a romanticized version of chemistry, how can I apply that to data transfer?

Comment: Why? You already have electricity Trying to convert electricity into chemicals for transmission and then back into electricity for said speaker or TV screen would be incredibly slow and inefficient. The transmission speed would be dictated by the speed of the water flow.

Comment: Steampunk cogs would be faster and more efficient.

Comment: This is one of the best questions ever asked on this site. The more you like exercising your imagination, the better you will like this question.

Comment: It's a bit more primitive but if the chemical way doesn't work, you could have miniaturised bottled messages that go through tap water. Like the ones you see in black and white science fiction films zipping around in clear glass tubes. :)

Comment: The technology you are looking for is called "fluidics". The 19th century developed this as a communications technology in the UK with air pressure devices. It was easily superseded by electrical systems like telegraphy and telephony. Variations in pressure can be transmitted along pipes. The main problem will be connecting to specific addresses. It might work better as a mass communications medium.

Comment: What's wrong with cables? Doesn't this country have telegraph and telephone?

Comment: If you can't use electricity, then this solution would be unbelievably slow.  Data would only move as fast as water is brought into a home which, compared to electricity, is impossibly slow.  If electricity is allowed, then someone will quickly realize that metal cables move electricity faster and more reliably than water.  Your question is a clever idea, but it will only work in your story if you avoid the details.

Comment: Electric cars held the speed record until 1902

Comment: Are you looking specifically for a solution that a chemist would be able to come up with, or solutions in general?  Most solutions I can draw from use physics (pressure, displacement, etc.) rather than chemical compounds

Comment: I'm definitely favoring chemical means; the world I'm designing has factions with a better grasp on other areas of science.

Answer (score 9):

There are projects looking at ways to use the water column within a pipe to acoustically transmit data.

https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/ett.3219

> The working principle of the node is that it magnetically clips onto a
>   pipe or valve, and either generates an acoustic vibration (transmitter
>   mode) or analyzes the vibration of the pipe (receiver mode). In
>   transmitter mode, the microcontroller generates a waveform (analog
>   voltage), which is amplified by the haptic driver and applied to the
>   macrofiber composite (MFC) piezo. Acoustic vibrations induced by the
>   piezo are then transferred via the magnetic resonator into the pipe or
>   valve, and relayed through the water column to a receiving node. Every
>   node in the system can be constructed identically. Nodes can switch
>   between the transmitter and receiver modes. Each node costs under US
>   $100 at unit price, addressing the requirement to keep costs low.

Vibrations will travel a long way through a contiguous water column - this is why you can hear things at great distances underwater.  You could send vibrations down the pipe to carry your digital data.  It could be like a fax message, or morse code depending on what kind of resolution your receiver has.

Also note that these nodes can switch between receiver and transmitter.  They can act as relay stations, receiving a message and then retransmitting it along.  This can compensate for signal loss with distance.

Comment: Awesome. Also, sound travels faster in water than in air, so that's another reason to use water rathen than empty pipes to transmit data.

Comment: Some numbers: the speed of sound on air at sea level is in the order of 330 meters per second. In fresh water, it is around 1480 meters per second, and around +20 m/s faster in seawater. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_sound#Speed_of_sound_in_liquids

Answer (score 5):

The problem with using chemicals in water for digital information is that the chemicals would need to arrive at the tap in the same order they were sent. While this will *sort of* occur during conventional fluid dynamics, the loss of precision would mean that you'd not be working with a very high bandwidth on this at all.

That said, there is a solution; [Laminar Flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laminar_flow). In fluid dynamics, laminar flow is the liquid equivalent of lasers. It affords coherent flow of fluids through things like water pipes and the like, and as I understand it many of the fire fighting nozzles for hoses are designed to generate laminar flow to make the water go further as a coherent stream from the nozzle than would normally be possible before it turns into a spray or mist.

You could use chemicals in this flow, but if you want to preserve the ability to drink the water at the same time, you could experiment with some form of pulsed laminar flow from the tap. Water glasses would fill but the water would be coming out in very fast pulses, which if you get the system working well may look similar to a conventional flow of water in any event. BUT, a sensitive pressure valve may be able to read the intermittent slight drops in pressure as 0s and 1s, allowing you to transmit data over the (tap) line.

To be sure, this would require a very sophisticated plumbing system to be in place, but the reality is that without laminar flow, your chances of putting the chemical *sequence* together at the other end would be practically non-existent. Additionally, pulsed laminar flow could be detected via a pressure valve on a constant basis, meaning that so long as you have water flowing from a single tap (designed for this purpose) you can record the data being transmitted. That water could then be stored for sending back to a central location, allowing for a user to transmit data back via a 'return' pipe. It would also mean that you should (in theory at least) still be able to use your plumbing system for its original intent as well, which is dispensing water for household use.

I want to stress that I know there are some BIG holes in this model. Drawing a bath may well alter the pressure on the valve (although it should be able to detect *relative* pressure pulses), water pressure on the return trip may not be very high (unless you pump it into a gravity feed tank, kind of like a water antenna) and unless you have a separate supply pipe for every home, you're going to have a massively difficult time doing the equivalent of IP routing. Still, if it's all you've got, these problems are really engineering matters that would get solved with sufficient application of ingenuity.

All in all, water transmission would be difficult, but not impossible.

Comment: Even in laminar flow, the velocity of the water in the pipe is not uniform, the layer closest to the pipe wall will be much slower than that of the central channel.

Comment: Hi @GaryWalker you're right; that is one of those BIG holes in the model. It's not a perfect system I'm proposing here, or even *completely* science based. This answer should be read as being speculative.

Answer (score 2):

As my first proposal stepped on faction toes- for which I apologize-I offer another solution. https://news.wisc.edu/chemical-dial-controls-attraction-between-water-repelling-molecules/  see link for full details. you said digital and i thought on or off. a chemical coating around a small sphere that makes it on or off according to your whim and a flow bypass triggered by a membrane allowing the spheres to interact with another receptor membrane at their destination. simple compounds could be deposited on the receptor or on the spheres before making a round trip back to the sender. Slow but definitely digital information transfer and more with some imagination. A chemical solution presented.

Comment: Not the way blood cells carry oxygen. - Data should be encoded in "junk" segments of DNA that the living plankton cells never naturally express, but that can be decoded from the pureed cells via a very fast DNA analysis process.

Comment: @A. I. Breveleri But, does that DNA analysis process use a computer with electronic components? You start to run into a "turtles all the way down" problem.

Comment: It is possible to build a very powerful computer without any understanding of electromagnetism whatsoever. If they understand chemistry then they understand materials enough to create transistors. Electronic components do not require wireless technologies.

Comment: Yeah, they have computers. I'm assuming computation is a universally-understood concept in my world; this is specifically a question about broadcasting. And I'd love to use bioengineering, but there's a different faction who already has a monopoly on biotech.

Answer (score 2):

If you're transferring information on a medium that doesn't effectively limit packet loss, your message has to be repeated many, many times. This would either take forever, or require encoding individual parts of the liquid itself.

The lowest-hanging fruit would be genetic encoding like DNA/RNA being placed in the medium to be 'drawn out', but this only slightly meshes with your theme.

My favorite (but a bit more difficult) means of communication could come in the form of complex covalent bonds acting like kanji (characters standing for words) along with one or more cipher molecules used to arrange/structure the other molecules to make a cogent thought.

So you might have a page molecule saying to look at paragraph molecule A, then paragraph molecule B, etc. And paragraph module A has reference to the order of kanji in the paragraph. Then you'd include every kanji in the document to be assembled.

This would much better fit with the alchemy theme, but wouldn't allow for different messages in a short period of time or back-and-forth messages. It'd work best as a passive news system: Flood today's news in the pipes from 9-5, and then flush the pipes for a few hours so you can start again tomorrow.